# Dictionary Apps for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, dictionary

I like to use default "Dictionary" app for seeking unknown meanings for Mac.

Are there any freeware app with additional (add-on) dictionaries you recommend over that default app? Any suggestions are most welcome.

**UPDATE**: I've tried Omni Dictionary. yes, it's a nice one but I could only use when I'm online. So that,

is there any way to use in offline Omni Dictionary or any good(need to be offline one) alternative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a few plug-ins to Apple's Dictionary App available. You can find two of them at the site of Tekl, who is the author of them. There are links provided to other dictionaries at the bottom of the site.

http://www.tekl.de/english/Dictionary_Plugins.html

Answer (score 3):

I suggest [OmniDictionary](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidictionary/) from Omnigroup. It is a dict client, which means that it can access a wide variety of dictionaries on-line (including very popular ones such as Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary).

Comment: it's a nice one but I could only use when I become online.